# fcntl F_SETOWN on Linux and OS X

Tags: python, linux, macos, fcntl

On Linux (Ubuntu 14.04), using the default python (2.7.6), the following works to correctly set the owner of stdin to the current process so that we receive SIGIO interrupts:

```
import os, sys, fcntl
fcntl.fcntl(sys.stdin, fcntl.F_SETOWN, os.getpid())
```

However on OS X (10.9.2) the same line in the default python (2.7.5) returns:

```
IOError: [Errno 25] Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Neither the OS X manpage for fcntl or the Linux equivalent, or the python docs give any help.

What's happening?